# Unlink Form from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google sheets spreadsheet with few sheets named: "Form Responses 1", "Form Responses 2", "Form Responses 3" and "Sheet1".
I wrote a code that delete all sheets except "Sheet1":

When I make run the function it gives me an error:

> You cannot delete a sheet with a linked form. Please unlink the form first.

How can I unlink the Form from the sheet?
See the code of the function below.

```
function clearForms()
{


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numsheets = ss.getNumSheets()-1;
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();


  var i=numsheets;

  while (i >=0)
 {
   if ( sheets[i].getName() != "Sheet1") {
      Logger.log(sheets[i].getName()+" Deleted");
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
   }
   i--;
 }  
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In the sheets menu bar, form-> unlink form while in the response sheet

Comment: And yeah, no way to do it programmatically yet: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3433

Answer (score 9):

Use the workaround as follows;

```js
var formUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getFormUrl();
if (formUrl)
  FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).removeDestination();
```

This will work even if the Form has been trashed using;

```js
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
```

But it still wont work if the file has been *permanently* deleted.

Answer (score 6):

`Menu bar -> Form-> Unlink form` while in the response sheet:

[image]

Comment: I know how to do it throughout th UI, but is there any way doing it with script?

Comment: no way to do it programmatically yet: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3433

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete sheet if it is connected / linked with any Google form,
Open that form -> go to "Form"=>"Unlink Form" menu. now you can run your script successfully.

Answer (score 0):

On the Google Sheet menu bar follow: Tools > Manage forms > Unlink form